# Angular Router nested Resolve(s)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: MoyComponent,
        resolve: {
            first: MyFirstResolver
            second: mySecondResolver(first)
        }
    }
```

I have a Resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFirstResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private ms: MyService, private router: Router) {}
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        let id = route.params['id'];
        return this.ms.get(id).map(res => {
            if (res) {
                return res;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`MyFirstResolver` returns an object `obj` which I would like to pass `obj['price']` to `mySecondResolver` as `mySecondResolver` depends on the `price` property of `obj`. How can I pass the result(s) from `myFirstResolver` to `mySecondResolver` ?

Comment: you are having two `return statements`

Comment: I don't understand @Aravind

Comment: you may need to consolidate them into it's own resolver. In theory, you could simply make a ThirdResolver class, import the first two, and chain them together.

Comment: @wilsonhobbs, that sounds interesting, if you can post a response, I will mark it as complete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consolidate both resolvers into a single resolver and chain them: so create ThirdResolver, and import the other two resolvers and chain their `resolve` methods together.

Comment: Can you provide a short sample? How can we chain the first two resolvers on the 3rd one?